# Delete only join record between tables in Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 3 Rails models as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :char_factors
end

class CharFactor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class UserCharFact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :char_factor
end
```

In the above `User` and `CharFactor` models are joined through the `UserCharFact` model.

I'm creating new relations as:

```
def create
  @user_character = UserCharFact.create({:user_id => @user.id, :char_factor_id => factor_id.id})
end
```

And the above seems to be working properly. But I can't find a way to delete a specific `join relation` between 2 tables. I tried the following:

```
def destroy
  @user_character = CharFactor.find(params[:id])
  @user.char_factors.delete(@user_character)
end
```

But it actually deletes the value from `CharFactor` table rather than just deleting the association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserCharFact.where(char_factor_id: params[:id], user_id: @user.id).destroy_all`

Answer (score 1):

You delete it just like you delete any other model records.

```
user_char_factor = UserCharFactor.find_by(user_id: user_id, char_factor_id: char_factor_id)
user_char_factor.destroy if user_char_factor
```